# Refresh app cache on expiry in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# WebAPI that has a query which collates a lot of data. Subsequently, I am using HttpRuntime cache to cache the result object for 10 mins. The problem is, when the cache expires, that person gets a 12 second load. This application utilises 3 delivery servers and we don't have the option of distributed cache.

Using .NET, we can use the cache expired event, but how best to use that without impacting the calling request?

One thought was to have a never expires cache, so that if the main cache is expired, fallback to that, then have a windows service or similar which polls every 5 mins to refresh both caches.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps caching the results separately to the page cache will help.
Based on http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/12/10/c-cache-helper-class/

Since it is static, you could use WCF to refresh at your own pace.

I modified to be static and not http

```
public static class CacheHelper
{
    public static void WriteOutCacheHelper()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> cache in Cache)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cache.Key);
        }
    }
    public static void WriteOutCacheHelper(string key)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Get<object>(key).ToString());
    }

    public static bool Enabled { get; set; }

    private static Dictionary<string, object> _cache;
    public static Dictionary<string, object> Cache
    {
        get
        {
            if (_cache == null) _cache = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            return _cache;
        }
    }

    public static object lockObject = new object();
    public static void Add<T>(T o, string key) 
    {
        if (!Enabled) return;

        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (Exists(key))
                Cache[key] = o;
            else
                Cache.Add(key, o);
        }
    }

    public static void Clear(string key)
    {
        if (!Enabled) return;

        Cache.Remove(key);
    }

    public static bool Exists(string key)
    {
        if (!Enabled) return false;
        return Cache.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public static T Get<T>(string key) 
    {
        if (!Enabled) return default(T);

        T value;
        try
        {
            value = (!Exists(key) ? default(T) : (T) Cache[key]);
        }
        catch
        {
            value = default(T);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static void ClearAll(bool force = false)
    {
        if (!force && !Enabled) return;
        Cache.Clear();
    }

    public static List<T> GetStartingWith<T>(string cacheKey) where T : class
    {
        if (!Enabled) new List<T>();

        return Cache.ToList().FindAll(f => f.Key.StartsWith(cacheKey, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            .Select(s => s.Value as T).ToList();
    }
}
```